# Небольшая задачка

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такая вот задачка, однако не до конца понимаю, как её реализовать, и как должен выглядеть код, ес

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SomeClass> list = Arrays.asList(
                new SomeClass(1, "Test1"),
                new SomeClass(2, "Test1"),
                new SomeClass(3, "Test1"),
                new SomeClass(4, "Test2"),
                new SomeClass(5, "Test2"),
                new SomeClass(6, "Test3"),
                new SomeClass(7, "Test3"),
                new SomeClass(8, "Test4"));

        // Заводим HashMap. 
        // В нем ключи могут идти не по алфавиту при выводе, если надо по алфавиту используйте TreeMap.
        Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>(); 
        for (SomeClass item : list) {
            if (!map.containsKey(item.name)) {
                // Такого ключа еще нет, создаем пустой список для него
                map.put(item.name, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            map.get(item.name).add(item.id); // Добавляем id в список
        }

        // Выводим
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue().toArray()));
        }
    }

    static class SomeClass {
        int id;
        String name;

        SomeClass(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

У меня вывод такой:

```
Test1 [1, 2, 3]
Test4 [8]
Test3 [6, 7]
Test2 [4, 5]
```